# javac error message does not display entire filepath

Tags: vim, compiler-errors, javac, java

When using javac (or the ant task ), the error message does not include the entire filepath, it only includes the file name. For example,

```
$ javac src/path/to/Filename.java
Filename.java:1: package foo.bar does not exist
import foo.bar.Baz;
              ^
```

What I would like is,

```
$ javac src/path/to/Filename.java
src/path/to/Filename.java:1: package foo.bar does not exist
import foo.bar.Baz;
              ^
```

My problem is that vim quickfix does not work if it's not given the entire filepath, not just the filename. With just the filename, a new empty file is opened up after running :make.

I'm using:

- Debian wheezy
- openjdk-6-jdk v6b23~pre7-1
- javac v1.6.0_23

Comment: I found if using gcj or the eclipse build-in compiler, the full path will be printed. But the ant will also print a JAVA_HOME can't found error. I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: I'm 99% sure this is an Ubuntu bug. I just switched my laptop to Ubuntu 11.10 from FreeBSD. I can see the entire path with a javac error on my FreeBSD server, too. Still looking for the solution...

Comment: Is there any way to implement it ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a simple way to do this.

However, I believe that there is a complicated way.  It basically involves writing your own compiler runner that makes use of a JDK installation's ability to load and run the Java compiler inside of a running program.  You need to implement a lot of stuff, but the key thing is a diagnostic processor that formats the compiler error messages in the way that you need them to be formatted.

Here are some relevant links:

- [Package `javax.tools`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/package-summary.html#package_description) - provides interfaces for tools which can be invoked from a program, for example, compilers.
- [`JavaCompiler`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) - the interface implemented by the compiler
- [`FileObject`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/FileObject.html) - the interface that the compiler uses to represent source files; e.g. in diagnostics.  Note the `toUri()` method!