# Maven compile error with full path to file

Tags: java, maven, compilation

I am trying to get the full path to the file that the build is failing on however, my compile is only listing the name of the Java file (as shown below). I've searched and have yet to find an answer. There are other developers that are able to see the full path to the file in question...

I'm left to believe that it's because I am on a Ubuntu box and they are using a Mac.

```
[ERROR] RLXidEventParser.java:[14,0] The import com.google.code.or.binlog.BinlogParserContext cannot be resolved
[ERROR] RLXidEventParser.java:[15,0] The import com.google.code.or.binlog.impl.event.XidEvent cannot be resolved
[ERROR] RLXidEventParser.java:[16,0] The import com.google.code.or.binlog.impl.parser.XidEventParser cannot be resolved
```

Should look like

```
[ERROR] /home/bob/src/trunk/rest/of/path/RLXidEventParser.java:[14,0] The import com.google.code.or.binlog.BinlogParserContext cannot be resolved
[ERROR] /home/bob/src/trunk/rest/of/path/RLXidEventParser.java:[15,0] The import com.google.code.or.binlog.impl.event.XidEvent cannot be resolved
[ERROR] /home/bob/src/trunk/rest/of/path/RLXidEventParser.java:[16,0] The import com.google.code.or.binlog.impl.parser.XidEventParser cannot be resolved
```

Comment: Can you explain in detail so that I can have better understanding of issue.

Comment: It seems a missing dependency

Comment: @Raffaele My question has absolutely nothing to do with the error I am getting.

Comment: I am on Ubuntu also. I put a syntax error in, to force an error and the error included the full path. Maybe it has to do with your JDK or maven version.

Comment: @WillShackleford Running Java 8 with maven 3.3.3.

Comment: Is anything different if run in debug mode (with `-X`)?

Comment: @user944849 Yeah I tried with -e as well, nothing. I want to rip my hair out. Seems like a trivial answer / solution.

Comment: I just noticed for me I am getting full paths running maven on the command line and relative paths in the output window of Netbeans.  Seems to be the same JDK (1.8.0_60) and maven(3.0.5) on both.

Comment: @WillShackleford Strange... I would understand if it was in reverse because then I wouldn't feel so crazy... but you are having the opposite result. I just confirmed with a developer who has the full path that he is running 3.2.3... About to give this a shot.

Comment: @WillShackleford Same result. Fml

Comment: It depends on the compiler implementation and the tool that wraps it. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7136283/315306)